# Configuring and triggering automated test enviroment in Azure

Tags: azure

I am fairly new to Azure and is investigating how to best do things. I have three environments (test, pre-prod and Prod) and would like to create some new environments for running automated tests.

1. How do I best create a new environment? Each consists of VMs,
   services, service bus, database and key vault and a few other
   issues. Do I simply duplicate every single item and configure it to
   point to the new source? Surly there is a more scalable way of doing
   this?
2. When do I trigger my integration tests to run? Say I update Service
   A and B and I need both to finish deploying to the auto-test
   environment before the test can start (say the change caused the
   interface between them to change)

   Do I start when A is delivered and then stop it when B finishes

   Do I start it when A id delivered and a new when B is delivered?

   Do I start when there is nothing in the build queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ARM Templates are the native way of creating resources in Azure, you can also look at ansible, for example. They both use principle known as "Infrastructure as Code".
2. I think the answer to that question depends on what you want to achieve (if I read and understand the question correctly), you can add testing steps after release of each service, or you can create a separate build\release for tests and run that independently of releases.

Comment: It looks like ARM addresses the first issue. For the second: I know how to add a testing step after build/deploy. But say I want to run a integration test between two services, how do I ensure both have been updated/deployed before starting the test?

Comment: i dont think there's an ability for release to depend on 2 other releases being successful in Azure Devops yet